# PHP require 'guzzle.phar' throws Fatal Error but on page refresh works

Tags: php, require, guzzle, phar

I want to use [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/releases/tag/6.5.2) in my project without using Composer(limitation I can't avoid). I have downloaded their phar file in my project directory `PROJECT_ROOT/includes/guzzle.phar`

Now in my other files if I use require_once or include or include_once it throws Fatal Error below:

```
PHP Fatal error:  
require(): Failed opening required 'phar://guzzle.phar/autoloader.php (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:PROJECT_ROOT/includes') in PROJECT_ROOT/includes/guzzle.phar on line 3
```

But when I use

```
require 'includes/guzzle.phar'
```

it throws the above error first time the page loads but when I refresh it doesn't throw any error and works ok after that.

Over the past two days, I have looked at various SO questions, tried using `include_once`, `include`, `require_once` and adding `PROJECT_ROOT` to include path but nothing seems to work.

Any help is appreciated and do let me know if any more info is needed. Thanks

Comment: Do you have `phar` extension on your server? How about misconfiguration of permissions?

Comment: use getcwd() function for get current working directory

Comment: I do have phar extension and getcwd doesn't change anything. The issue is phar does get loaded with 'require' command but on the first load, it crashes. After that when I refresh, it gets works perfectly.

Comment: It works like a charm for me. With what server are you running PHP? FPM? Apache? Do you by any chance have a opcode-cache enabled like https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php or https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php? What PHP and what guzzle version are you using?

Comment: Just download the zip package instead of the phar, uncompress and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned `PHP Fatal` error will throw only if the file path is in correct, you can also find Warnings mentioning the file path is incorrect just before the `Fatal error`.

```
PHP Fatal error:  
require(): Failed opening required 'phar://guzzle.phar/autoloader.php (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:PROJECT_ROOT/includes') in PROJECT_ROOT/includes/guzzle.phar on line
```

On each `Error/Warning/Notice` PHP include information about the error cause to help the developer to track the issue.

`Failed opening required 'phar://guzzle.phar/autoloader.php`

From the above `line/code` you can find that the `guzzle.phar` file path is incorrect, try to use an absolute path insted of relative one.

`require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].""."includes/guzzle.phar"`